# How to validate a XML against a DTD (Document Type Definition) using C++?

Tags: c++, xml, dtd

The requirement is to validate a XML file against a DTD. For an example following xml file could be considered which has its own embedded DTD.

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8" standalone = "yes" ?>
<!DOCTYPE address [
   <!ELEMENT address (name,company,phone)>
   <!ELEMENT name (#PCDATA)>
   <!ELEMENT company (#PCDATA)>
   <!ELEMENT phone (#PCDATA)>
]>

<address>
   <name>Tanmay Patil</name>
   <company>TutorialsPoint</company>
   <phone>(011) 123-4567</phone>
</address>
```

The solution must be in C++ language

Comment: There are various C or C++ XML parsers like Xerces-C++ https://xerces.apache.org/xerces-c/ or libxml so select one and use it.